# LaTex question about graphics

Tags: beamer, graphics

How can I put a picture or graphic file in my Beamer presentation?

Comment: You can use `\includegraphics`. (The `graphicx` package gets automatically loaded by `beamer`.)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `\includegraphics` as suggested by @TikZling

See below for the implementation:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image} 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The output would be:
[image]